# CSS not loading properly in jsp, tomcat and servlet

Tags: css, jsp, tomcat, servlets

[image: Directory of My Project]
Login.css

```
body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: url(../images/bg.png) 0 64px repeat-x;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    xmargin: 0 auto;
}

#border-top.h_green {
    background: url(../images/j_header_middle.png) repeat-x;
    height: 84px;
    xmargin: 0 auto;
}

#contentbox {
    width: 755px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    xbackground: #efefef;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
#header-top {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    xbackground: #efefef;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#menuheader {
    position: relative;
}

#contentbox p {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#menubox {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #cccecc;
    border-right: 1px solid #cccecc;
    height: 15px;
}

#user_name {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    xbackground: url(../../../images/icons/user.png) no-repeat scroll 0 2px
        transparent;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
}

.loginwrapper {
    width: 755px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn{ 
    background:url(../images/btn.jpg) repeat-x;
    height:28px;
    border:none;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.loginbox {
    background: url(../images/login_shadow.png) no-repeat;
    height: 310px;
    padding: 40px;
}

.rightsection {
    width: 85%;
    float: right;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccc;
}

.rightboxwrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 325px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    background: url(../images/loginleft.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    height: 262px;
}

.rightboxwrapper .loginheader h2 {
    color: #0588ab;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: trebuchet MS;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.loginform input {
    width: 170px;
}

.loginform input#btnsubmit {
    width: 80px !important;
    border: none;
}

.loginform {
    padding: 10px 0 0 45px;
    line-height: 35px;
    background: url(../images/lock.png) no-repeat right center;
    width: 335px;
}

.loginform td {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.copyright {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    font-size: 11px;;
    color: #0588ab;
    font-family: trebuchet MS;
}

.copyright p {
    padding-right: 15px !important;
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#commentForm1").validate({meta: "validate"});
                required: 'Enter this!'
            });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
form { width: 500px; }
form label { width: 250px; }
form label.error, 
form input.submit { color: red; font-size: 20px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<!--maindiv wrapper starts-->
    <div id="border-top" class="h_green">
      <!--header starts-->
      <div id="header-top">

        <div><img width="249" height="54" style="padding:15px 0 0 0px" src="images/companylogo.png"> </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div id="contentbox">
<div style="background:none;border:none;" id="menubox">
  <div id="menuheader">
    <div id="message">
      <p style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px;" class="message_text"> </p>

    </div>
    <div id="user_name">
          </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="loginbox">
<div style="width:100%!important;" class="rightsection">

    <form name="loginform" action="loginServlet" method="post" id="commentForm1">

        <div class="loginwrapper">

            <div class="rightboxwrapper">

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="loginform">
           <tbody><tr class="loginheader">
            <th style="color:#0588ab; font-size:12px; font-family:Helvetica; text-transform:uppercase; height:35px;"> <h2>Login</h2></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="color:#0588ab; font-size:12px; font-family:Helvetica; text-transform:uppercase; height:25px;">User ID </td></tr>
            <tr>

            <td style="color:#0588ab; font-size:12px; font-family:Helvetica; text-transform:uppercase; height:25px;"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="{validate:{required:true, messages:{required:'*'}}}"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td style="color:#0588ab; font-size:12px; font-family:Helvetica; text-transform:uppercase; height:25px;">Password</td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="color:#0588ab; font-size:12px; font-family:Helvetica; text-transform:uppercase; height:25px;"><input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="{validate:{required:true, messages:{required:'*'}}}"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
           <td colspan="2">
         <input value="Login" class="btn"  style="width:60px;" type="submit"/>
         <input value="Reset" class="btn" style="width:60px; margin-left:10px;" type="reset"/>
         </td>


         </tr>

        </tbody></table>
            </div>
            <div class="imagewrapper">
            <img width="323px" height="262px" src="images/loginimg.png">     

            </div>
         </div> <div style="clear:both; color:fff"></div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="cleared"></div>

</div>

 <div id="footerwrapper"><!--Div for the Footer -->
    <div class="copyright">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2012 BitsCrafters HRM All rights reserved.</p>
    </div><!--ended Footer Div-->
 </div>   
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with this code? can anyone help me out of this? There is something wrong because when i run it through tomcat sometime its work but sometime it doesn't work some icon and image is not displayed. In browser i checked view source to check whether css path is correct or not it is correct.

Comment: Where is your css directory within Tomcat? What are the URLs of the pages i.e. what do they look like in the user's browser? (Post an example). My guess is that the path to the login.css is not correct relative to the URL of your page.

Comment: Martin Wilson i have updated my question where i have added image that shows Directory of MY project,Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your call to include the css file?  <link type="text/css" href="css/login.css">

Comment: @John Moses oh sorry while pasting code i forget now i have edited my question.

Comment: Do users access the jsp pages directly, e.g. is the URL whatever:8080/myapp/index.jsp?

Comment: yes martin url localhost:8080/HRDB/index.jsp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran into the same, just correct the href path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/login.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code and CSS look correct at first glance, so the error is elsewhere.

1. Use a tool like Firebug or "Inspect Element" to check what your browser gets. All these tools have a network tab where you can see what the browser requested and what it got. Look for:

   1. Do you see all the URLs that you expect?
   2. Could the server serve all these (HTTP status 200)
   3. Check the content of the files. Do they contain what you expect?
2. Check the error console. Do you get any CSS / JavaScript errors?
3. Inspect the element in question. Does it have the correct CSS styles? In the CSS panel, do you see the correct styles?

Comment: Sir yes i have used firebug its all fine. Sometime my project works well i.e loading all the css class and id, but if i refresh the page i will find some icon missing.I am frustrated with this problem.

Comment: So what does Firebug say when the refresh failed? Did you check the error logs on the server side as well?